# Cant I just use a 24v wall instead of a tranformer?

Tags: furnace

I can just use a 24v wall transformer that I have plugged into my sprinkler system and use that in place of the transformer on my electric Central coleman furnace right?  I would connect the hot line to R thermastat wire then wire the other wires to the common wire.  If the transformer is in the unit is reducing the 120v to 24v then the wall outlet plug is essentially do the same thing.

Comment: Can you explain just what you are trying to achieve and why?

Comment: Whats wrong with using the transformer in the unit? Did it go bad, because you didn't say.

Comment: I think the question is whether a thermostat that requires a C wire could be powered from another source rather than from the furnace. Since I haven't had reason to learn how that setup works, I'd be guessing.

Comment: Check the amperage, too.   Does the wall wart have enough?

Comment: What is the model number of the heater?

Comment: The model is a coleman eb15a central electric furnace. Its cold im broke. How may amp does it. It the plug from my sprinkler system.

Comment: It appears that the transformer for your unit is a 24 V 40 VA transformer, which is quite common for HVAC controls.  It also appears that Sears Parts Direct has a [replacement for $20.97](http://www.searspartsdirect.com/Coleman-evcon-ind-Furnace-Parts/3400-3841@SLASH@A/0064/476/Model-EB15A/1804/0912120.html). If you're sure that's the problem, 20 bucks doesn't seem outrageous. Also, make sure you check for blown fuses in the unit, before you order the replacement.

Comment: It need 40 amps to run? Whats the VA?

Comment: VA is volt-amperes, and it describes the amount of power the transformer can supply. Basically at 24 volts, the transformer can supply 1.666 amperes.

Comment: Shit its not even close to that. So the transformer drops the voltage and calibrates the amps. Why so many amp to power a thermostat?

Comment: The transformer doesn't just power the thermostat (in fact, in most cases it doesn't even power the thermostat), it powers circuit boards and relays within the furnace.

Comment: Well theres no circuit board.  The relay and the sequencer both have power coming from the breaker right?

Answer (score 1):

If it is a match - 24/vac and rated for the necessary amperage and duty cycle - it will run the controls.  However the furnace manufacturer's / local code requirements will probably demand a permanently wired unit.

Comment: Installing the transformer at the thermostat is going to be troublesome.